# Drupal event listings (showing the date, month, title and body of the event content)

Tags: drupal

I am trying to create a list of events on my drupal site. I have a problem with repeating events. 
This is what i am trying to replicate: http://sites.wustl.edu/marcia/upcoming-events/

but for me, on the repeating events, i have dates showing together in the red area. see attached image. [image]
How do i separate this out so the event is actually listed one event per date.
I use views, and the date module to create my events list.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I think [this](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/63825/show-repeating-event-just-once-in-views-while-sorting-by-date) is what you looking for.

Comment: Yes Sebastian, I actually got it to work yesterday, was gonna post the answer today. In the Views field configuration for the Date field: Hide Repeat Rule, then in the "Multiple Field Settings" fieldset, remove the checkbox for "Display all values in the same row".
Thank you , much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out a few hours after I posted question, Can't believe I missed it. Anyway, Thank you @Sebastian.

Basically I was missing a setting in the view that I needed to uncheck. I was basically telling the view to display all dates in the same row.
So all I needed to do was for the Date field: Hide Repeat Rule, then in the "Multiple Field Settings" fieldset, remove the checkbox for "Display all values in the same row" and viola!

[image]

Thank you, hope this helps someone too.